# Can I mount a Lightsail disk as a volume on a container service?

Tags: containers, amazon-lightsail

I need to mount a Lightsail disk as a volume on an Lightsail container service I want use to run a Docker container in. I need this for the persistent storage.

Is that possible or are Lightsail containers only good for stateless applications?

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question that was already answered here: https://serverfault.com/a/1076211/952369

TL;DR: you can't use Lightsail disks as persistent storage, what you could do instead in order to persist your data is to use S3 or other AWS services like RDS